# Laravel 4 Eloquent Capabilities

Tags: orm, laravel, relational-database, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to the Laravel, I used to work on codeigniter.
I am fascinated by concepts of Eloquent ORM.
I have a generic question about the capability of Eloquent.
What is the capability of the ORM, What I mean is to what level we can get the related table rows.
If you look at "http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

- One To One
- One To Many
- Many To Many
- Polymorphic Relations.

In my opinion 
"One To One" means level 1. table1 table2

`Example: User::find(1)->posts;`

[internally find user 1 and his posts]

"Many To Many" means level 2. table1 table2 table3:

```
Example: User::find(1)->postcomments
```

[internally find user 1 and his post and find the comments of the posts]

So, Can we extend this to 4 levels or 5 levels.

Database relations[item(id) -itemtag(id, itemid, tagid) - tag(id) - tagtype(id, tagid, typeid) - type(id)]

Thanks

================

## Following post

Though i like msturdy's explanation  but i could not make the code work that way he explained.

Here is my code with database tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `role` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;


CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5;


CREATE TABLE `student_role` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `student_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `role_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_student_role_1_idx` (`student_id`),
    INDEX `fk_student_role_2_idx` (`role_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_student_role_1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_student_role_2` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Models

class Student extends Eloquent {

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'student_role');
}
```

}

class Role extends Eloquent {

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'student_role');
}
```

}

```
Route::get('aaaas/{id}', function($id){

$student = Student::find($id);

$studentstr = print_r($student->toArray(), true);
print "<pre>student: $studentstr</pre>";

$roles = print_r($student->roles->toArray(), true);
print "<pre>role: $roles</pre>";
```

}

================

Above code works fine

but 
$student->roles->students

does not work as expected.
It will be great if we can have a working code to support your answer.

But anyways thanks for the explanation.

Comment: With the second argument to `belongsToMany` you need to pass the COLUMN of your table that's used to make the connection... not the table name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not quite the way it works, take another look at the example given in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

**one-to-one**

Here we have is a direct relationship between two models, in the example, a `User` and his `Phone`.  I know this isn't the case in the real world.. but here there are **only one of each on each side of the relationship**.  So:

- `$user->phone` will only ever return one item, his `Phone`..
- `$phone->user` will ever return one item, the Phone's owner (`User`)

We have 2 tables, `users` and `phones`, linked by the `user_id` in the `phones` table

**one-to-many**

Here we can use the example of the `User` and his `Post`s.  On one side of the relationship, there is one thing, on the other there can be 1 or more items.

- `$user->posts` will return a collection of the `Post`s made by our `User`.
- `$post->user` will return the `User` for any one of his `Post`s.

However, we still have only 2 tables, `users` and `posts`, linked by the `user_id` in the `posts` table.

**many-to-many**

Following on from that, now we can have a relationship where on each side, there can be more than one thing... let's use the example of `User`s and `Role`s from the Laravel docs

A single `User`, can have any number of `Role`s, and a `Role`s can appear on any number of `User`s... now we have:

- `$user->roles` will show the `Role`s for that `User`

Now we have to have 3 tables, `users`, `roles` and `role_user`, where the `role_user` table contains a mapping of the `user_id`s and `role_id`s.

If you have a second many-to-many relationship between, say, `User` and `Town`, then you'll need two more tables, `towns` and `town_user`, to be able to link these two models.

Now, and I think this is what you were getting at with your question, you can put these together to draw relationships between any number of models.. here's a simple example for a few one-to-many and many-to-many relationships:

```
// Our User model
class User extends Eloquent {

    // one-to-many with Post
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    // one-to-many with Role
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
}

// Our Role model
class Role extends Eloquent {

    //many-to-many with User
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}

// Our Post model definition
class Post extends Eloquent {

    // one-to-many with User
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    // many-to-many with Tag
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}

// Our Tag model definition
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    // many-to-many with Post
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Which means that:

- `$user->posts` will give you a `User`'s `Post`
- `$user->posts->tags` could give you a collection of `Tag`s that are assigned to the `Post`s that a user has made
- `$role->users->posts` could give you a collection of `Post`s that were made by `User`s with a specific `Role`

..and so on and so on!  Hope that's made it clearer?  :)

Comment: Though I like your explanation, I could not able to put what you said in a working code.

Comment: OK, well.. think about what you're trying to do, make an attempt at the solution, and then post your efforts here, with your code!  :)  Then we can have a look at it, and give you some pointers.. Once you get it into your head, you'll find it makes a lot of sense!